# Kibana stuck on loading screen [UPDATE - Nginx only serving partial JS file]

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, nginx, browser, kibana

Kibana is not starting up properly. When I open up the console it appears to be a javascript resource issue. When I open the js files directly (clicking on their link in the console) it appears they are incomplete and have been abruptly been cut off. Not sure if this is a browser file limit or somehow my files have been cut off? Please see the images below to show you what Im seeing.

[image: Kibana stuck on loading screen]

File as seen in chrome. This is the very bottom of the file as per how chrome loads it.

[image: commons.bundle.js]

I have restarted kibana to see if that would resolve it, no luck.

I think browsers have a max line limit in js files. I am not sure why kibana hasn't minified the js files? has it started up in some dev mode?

**question summary**

I guess I have discovered the reason for kibana not loading is because of the js not fully loading, this would change my question to how can I get all of my javascript to load?

**Update**

I have located the JS files in the kibana bundles folder and found that the file is fully intact. It is indeed a browser loading complete file issue. I'm confused why suddenly those files are too long to be loaded by the browser? Was working fine a fortnight ago. Still trying to work out how I can get chrome to load the files.

As suggested by @asettouf I have removed(backed up) `bundles` folder in the `/opt/kibana/optimize` directory and started kibana up again. This did re-generate the `bundles` folder but the files are identical, meaning I still have the same issue. How come Kibana is not minifying the js when it bundles the files for caching?

My **kibana.yml**. I think it is cleaner to paste a link to it:

> http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/O8HUN

went back turned on verbose logging and this is my output from deleting optimize folder and restarting. nothing stands out as an error message to me.

**/var/log/kibana/kibana.log**

replaced hostname with localhost for privacy and security reasons

> http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/OA4OR

I think this is an error with the webpack module not compiling the JS correctly. however i dont know enough about the module to debug it.

the files in question in the optimize folder are:

**commons.bundle.js** which is **65723 lines**

**kibana.bundle.js** at **108950 lines**

These are far from optimized and the content inside the files are not minified.

Result of `curl -v localhost:5601`

> http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/OEKEX

**CURL REQUEST DIRECTLY TO KIBANA JS RESOURCES**

I can confirm that `curl -ukibanaadmin -v http://localhost/bundles/commons.bundle.js` returns me the full 108950 lined JS file and `curl -ukibanaadmin -v http://actual_kibana_hostname/bundles/commons.bundle.js` returns the same content (number of lines) as my browser.

With that information I can make the assumption that this is not a Kibana issue  at all. As mentioned by @val it is probably a setting in nginx that is preventing the entire file from being served unless accessed by localhost.

I think I can rule out Cloudflare as I still get the issue when I hit my server directly from the browser.

**Thanks**  to everyone's suggestions and help so far. Getting closer and closer to solving my issue. I will do some more research on Nginx and its settings.

**NGINX UPDATE**

Nginx appears to only be loading the first 72kbs of my havascript files. Ive search all around  my nginx config files and cannot see this setting anywhere. Ive added things like

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 1m;
    ...
}
```

and

```
location / {
    ...
    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;

    ...
}
```

But still I'm unable to overwrite this weird setting that is only allowing first part of file being loaded.

The connection uses nginx `proxy_pass` to foward port `80` to kibanas port '5601'. I feel like there could be a setting that limits file transfer over proxy? just not sure where to find it.

proxypass connection looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name logs.mydomain.com;

    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

And my default nginx settings is posted here.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

> http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/OEKIR

I have tried adding `sendfile_max_chunk 512k` and changed `worker_processes` from 4 to 2. Any other config things were already there. I was not the the one who initially set up the ELK stack.

And after the mentioned changes it looks like this:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

> http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/OEKF0

**ERROR RETURNED - DISK SPACE UPDATE**

This issue has come back. When I checked the VMs health I noticed that the disk drive was full. Elasticsearch was logging a couple of `GBs` worth of text in to error logs each day. I still Have not fully identified why elastic search is flooding the error logs.

But I think excessive disk space usage has contributed to this error. Nginx could be detecting this and switching over to minimal safe configuration which would only allow 72kbs of data to be served per file.

When I cleared out the excessive logs i stopped getting the incomplete js error  without needing to restart `nginx` or `kibana`.

Comment: Are you accessing Kibana behind a proxy? Do you have nginx in front of it or something like that? That error comes from a slow connection or some component between your browser and Kibana that slows down everything.

Comment: Yes. Cloudflare at the DNS layer and nginx as the webserver. was working fine for months and then last couple months been getting this issue

Comment: Can you try to access it directly and see if the problem persists? If that's not the case, then try to add one component after another and see which one causes the problem, it might not be Kibana at all.

Comment: have hit my server directly with the IP address (this takes out cloudflare proxy) and unfortunately the issue persist.  I need nginx to serve the kibana pages. Do you know how i could test nginx as the cause?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output you get from accessing your Kibana instance with `curl -v kibana_host` ?

Comment: One way to access Kibana directly from your computer without going through nginx is to set up an SSH tunnel using `ssh -L5601:kibana_ip:5601 user@bastion_host`. Then you can access Kibana through `localhost:5601`. Note that `bastion_host` is a publicly accessible host name from which you can access your Kibana instance located at `kibana_ip` (they can be the same host)

Comment: Also do a `curl -v localhost:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js` so we can compare both.

Comment: We need to compare the output of `curl -v kibana_ip/bundles/commons.bundle.js` and `curl -v localhost:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js` and probably also the same for `kibana.bundle.js`

Comment: @Val I Have updated my post. I think you are right about this being an nginx issue. Now i just got to work out what nginx settings i need to tweak. Thanks so much with the help you have given. Any further help or suggestions would be very much appreciated

Comment: It might probably be that the `sendfile_max_chunk` in your nginx config is too small. Try increasing it to `512k` instead.

Comment: Also you might have `worker_processes auto` which utilizes every available CPU. Try to lower that to `worker_processes 2` (if you have more than 2 cores or 1 if you have two cores) instead to leave some processing power for Node.js and other processes.

Comment: And finally, you might also want to enable gzip compression if not already

Comment: @Val i made the changes you suggested but still no luck. Have added my nginx.conf to my post to see if anyone can identify a setting i have wrong.

Comment: Are we sure that there are no additional configs in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` that override some http settings the main one?

Comment: Ping Jason Joslin  ;-)

Comment: My conf.d dir is empty. So i need to keep researching nginx settings.

Comment: @Val Ive started a new question specific to the assumed issue on top of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964555/nginx-only-serving-first-72kbs-of-my-js-files

Comment: Still unresolved. I thought now that its been narrowed down to an nginx issue a new question would be cleaner. But im a stackoverflow noob so whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: I would have kept it all in this context to prevent people from having to jump between a few questions to figure out the final solution + you invested some of your reps in the bounty which will get lost if no solution is posted here.

Comment: Roger. Will merge. Cheers

Comment: Can you add `proxy_buffering: off;` in your proxy config?

Comment: That may have worked. Will wait 24 hours before confirming. I wish to give you @Val the full bounty if this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're accessing Kibana behind a proxy, you'd need to bypass the proxy and see if the problem persists, i.e. compare the load times of

```
// through proxy
curl -v kibana_host/bundles/commons.bundle.js
curl -v kibana_host/bundles/kibana.bundle.js

// bypass proxy
curl -v localhost:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js
curl -v localhost:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js
```

If the load time is lower when you bypass the proxy then you know it's not a Kibana issue but more with the way your proxy is configured.

**UPDATE**

Since we've narrowed this down to a proxy issue, try to update your nginx config with this

```
sendfile_max_chunk 512k
worker_processes 2
```

**UPDATE 2**

Try another modification of your nginx configuration:

```
proxy_buffering: off;
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I Had another issue with logstash that I've now resolved. Just needed some time to fix logstash and let it run before crediting your answer. Kibana still up and running, so I can safely say that this was the fix. Thanks again for time you put in to helping me.